# Turn certain layers on and off in ArcGIS Web AppBuilder Developer Edition

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-web-appbuilder, widget

Does anyone know a way in ArcGIS Web AppBuilder Developer edition that I can **create a button or a link that turns certain layers on or off**?

For example, if I have three layers

[1] Homes 
[2] Rivers 
[3] Zip Codes

and I want to create a button that turns on layers [1] and [3], so that the user only has to click once to do this instead of twice.

(In reality, there are more like 20 layers, so the time savings would be significant)

Answer (score 5):

The [Layer Toggle Button widget](https://community.esri.com/docs/DOC-8592-layer-toggle-button-widget-version-214-01132020) is designed to do precisely that.

> This is just a simple widget to toggle a configured layer(s) on and off using a button. The layer(s) can be a whole map service layer or a specific sublayer(s) in a map service. This widget will sync with the LayerList widget. You can add multiple instances of this widget to onscreen place holders or in a widget controller like the Header controller in the Foldable theme.

See it in action here: https://gis.calhouncounty.org/wab/v2.14/widgets/LayerToggleButton/